# What do these table relationship symbols mean?

Tags: powerbi

My data model includes two tables with the relationship shown in the image. Notice the symbols highlighted in green. I have never seen these before. Can someone tell me what they mean?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that the relationship runs from an Import (in-memory) table to a DirectQuery table.  Notice the blue bar on the top of Sales and the "white bar" on the top of Calendar.

When building queries, PBI will have to include all the DateKey values in a big `IN` list, instead of being able to JOIN Sales to Calendar in SQL.

soemthing like

```
select * 
from sales 
where ORDER_DATE IN ('2020-01-01','2020-01-02',  ...
```

instead of

```
select s.* 
from sales s 
join calendar c
  on c.DATE_KEY =  s.ORDER_DATE
where c.CALENDAR_YEAR = 2021
```

Generally you should make these tables `Dual` instead of `Import` to avoid this issue.